# How to change Split View Background color dynamically in Windows 10 App

Tags: c#, windows-phone, windows-store-apps, windows-10

```
<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
        <SplitView x:Name="mySplitView" DisplayMode="CompactInline"  IsPaneOpen="False" 
                CompactPaneLength="50" OpenPaneLength="150" Content="{Binding}"> // using PaneBackground I can set color statically
            <SplitView.Pane>
                <StackPanel>
                    <Button x:Name="HamburgerButton" FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets" Content="&#xE700;"
                     Width="50" Height="50" Background="Transparent" Foreground="White"  Click="HamburgerButton_Click" />
            <StackPanel>
         </SplitView.Pane>
     </SplitView>
 </Grid>
```

.How to change the color of Splitview Pane dynamically i.e if a user clicks button to change color to yellow it should change and if user wants default accent color then that should be set just like in outlook Mail app. I have my split view in one page and want the buttons in other xaml page namely settings page.

Comment: Could you please add a picture of what you are trying to do

Comment: @StuartSmith of what you want the picture ?

Answer (score 3):

You can use 'PaneBackground' property be code and use this code in each item click event handler :

```
mySplitView.PaneBackground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Yellow);
```

Is this what you try to do ?

Comment: It works when my button and splitview are in same xaml files. But my split view is in Shell.xaml and I have a settings page which contains all buttons.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can use the theme.

1.In the App.xmal file ,you need add two theme resource

```
<Application
x:Class="App3.App"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:App3"
RequestedTheme="Light">
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.ThemeDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary x:Key="Light">
                <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush">#FFDEDEDE</SolidColorBrush>
            </ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary x:Key="Dark">
                <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush">Yellow</SolidColorBrush>
            </ResourceDictionary>
        </ResourceDictionary.ThemeDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

2.Change the MainPage's code

```
   public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        RequestedTheme=ElementTheme.Light;
    }

    private void HamburgerButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        RequestedTheme = ElementTheme.Dark;
    }
```

It should work in winrt.

Comment: It works but my concern is how to do it on button click that to my button being on different page. I have a shell.xaml which  has split view and I have a settings.xaml where I have all the buttons of color.

Comment: @shriyanshk Maybe you can take a look at [VLC git rep](http://git.videolan.org/?p=vlc-ports/winrt.git;a=shortlog),VLC have a similar case like your request

Answer (score 0):

The following can meet your requirements:

1. Button on setting page which is responsible for change color of split view in other pages. The new color can be saved into application's local setting.

   ```
   public sealed partial class SettingPage : Page
   {
       public SettingPage()
       {
           this.InitializeComponent();
       }

       private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
       {
           ApplicationDataContainer localsettings = ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings;
           localsettings.Values["SplitViewColoronShell"] = Colors.Yellow.ToString();
       }
   }
   ```
2. In the code behind of shell page, get the color from local setting and set it to the splitview.

   ```
   protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
   {
       base.OnNavigatedTo(e);
       ApplicationDataContainer localsettings = ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings;
       if (localsettings.Values["SplitViewColoronShell"] != null)
       {
           mySplitView.PaneBackground = GetSolidColorBrush(localsettings.Values["SplitViewColoronShell"].ToString());
       }
   }

   public SolidColorBrush GetSolidColorBrush(string hex)
   {
       hex = hex.Replace("#", string.Empty);
       byte a = (byte)(Convert.ToUInt32(hex.Substring(0, 2), 16));
       byte r = (byte)(Convert.ToUInt32(hex.Substring(2, 2), 16));
       byte g = (byte)(Convert.ToUInt32(hex.Substring(4, 2), 16));
       byte b = (byte)(Convert.ToUInt32(hex.Substring(6, 2), 16));
       SolidColorBrush myBrush = new SolidColorBrush(Windows.UI.Color.FromArgb(a, r, g, b));
       return myBrush;
   }
   ```